# How is it possible to have a buffer overrun on one platform but not another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, buffer-overrun

I'm hesitant to ask this question because of the vagueness of the situation, but I'd like to understand how this is possible. I have a C++ application developed using Visual Studio 2008. When I compile the application on Windows 7 64-bit (or Vista 32-bit), the application runs fine. When I compile the application on 32-bit Windows XP SP3, I receive a buffer overrun warning and the process terminates. This is using the same verison of the Visual Studio 2008 C++ compiler. How is it that I receive a buffer overrun on XP, but not on other Windows platforms?

Comment: Everything can happen when it comes to undefined behavior (eg nasal demons). Of course, you can be curious why exactly this happens but you shouldn't be surprised, that's the nature of UB :)

Comment: Probably some issue with integer or pointer sizes leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @André: there are no integer/pointer size differences between XP and Vista 32-bit.

Comment: When you *compile on* or when you *run on*?

Comment: @DeadMG In my case, I'm compiling on a given platform before running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write code so you don't have buffer overruns and you won't have this problem on any platform.  Namely, make sure you check the bounds for the buffer you are accessing to make sure you aren't trying to read/write outside of the proper bounds.

Comment: @Andre:  Yeah, who ever would try bounds checking to prevent from having a buffer overrun.

Comment: Me: "It hurts when I do this, doctor." Doctor: "Well, don't do that, then." I'm using remarkably few directly allocated buffers, preferring instead to rely on STL objects. Debugging in this particular instance shows that I'm receiving the buffer overrun notification during the destruction of a map, so that's throwing me off a little.

Comment: If you are using standard containers, set the bounds checking preprocessor directive (I can't remember what it is off the top of my head).  It will cause an exception to be thrown so you can find the error more easily.  What is your map holding?

Comment: Sorry but I agree with Andre. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Marlon:  Debugging is part art, part science.  If you ignore the tools given to you to help make it easier for you (in this case, bounds checking), you take away both and make it simply luck.

Comment: @Zac I am not disagreeing with you in any way. However, the OPs question was "what causes this problem?" and you provided him with a solution. I will give you +1 if you give an explanation to why he receives a buffer overrun in one situation while not the other.

Comment: He has a buffer overrun in both.  He just isn't seeing it propagated in the other.  When you go into the realm of undefined behavior, you get undefined results.

Comment: @Jim What else can the doctor say when the complaint is "It hurts when I run head-first into the wall"? If you're having a problem during the destruction of a map, and I had to make a guess, I would say you're violating the Rule of Three [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) ] in the class being stored in the map, causing the buffer overrun in the destructor of that class.

Comment: @Zac As it happens, the map is holding raw pointers to instances of other classes in the application. I'm discovering how this is suboptimal, as I'm leaking all over the place when the objects being pointed to don't get properly deleted. This is due to my inexperience with and ignorance of C++; I'm normally not, by training or inclination, a C++ developer.

Comment: @JimEvans:  From the sounds of it, you'll likely benefit from the use of smart pointers (`shared_ptr`, `scoped_ptr`, and friends).  Only manage pointers directly when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Luck, the fundamental undeterminedness of the Universe, or (more likely than the previous) an implementation detail that changed in msvcrt.dll between XP and 7.

Bottom line is you have a bug in your application, and you should fix it.

Comment: -1: I'm sorry but this provides no help at all.  OP already knows he has a bug.  He's looking for hints as to how to find it.

Comment: @André: no, he's asking exactly and clearly about the difference in behavior (read the question again if you don't believe me). The OP seems intelligent and literate enough to ask questions like yours with error messages and more details. What you are suggesting is that I answered with "Use a debugger to find the location of the overflow".

Comment: +1 Spot on - the OPs time is better spent finding and fixing the bug rather than unhelpful conjecture about why the undefined behaviour might change between platforms.

Comment: @rubenvb Since I'm building using the same version of Visual Studio, I was under the impression that I'd be using the same version of msvcrt.dll, but I suppose it's possible I'm not.

Comment: @JimEvans: there are several versions and editions of the crt: msvcrt.dll, msvcrt71.dll, msvcrt80.dll, msvcrt90.dll, msvcrt100.dll. The ones with version numbers are tied to a specific VS version. The first one though, is present on a standard Windows install (so without any Visual C++ redistributable packages installed) and is used as a default at least with MinGW. I don't know how the numbered and default ones differ, but I'm assuming several functions just get forwarded to the msvcrt.dll. Or some kind of low-level memory management type thing changed, which has a macroscopic consequence.

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, I take your point. I should have specified msvcrt90.dll in my comment, as all platforms in question have Visual Studio installed at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a buffer overrun in both case, in the first it isn't detected and doesn't (apparently) do any harm.  In the second it is detected. (If it is on a dynamically allocated memory, you have to know that allocators often allocate more than what asked, thus a plausible explanation is that in the first case the overrun stay in that zone, in the second it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Sizes of data types might change from one compiler to another (thanks @AndreyT). Using hardcoded numbers like `sizeof(4)` to represent the size of a data type on your code, might pop up a bug on your application. You should use `sizeof(int)` instead or whatever type you are interested in.

Comment: Size of data types do not depend on the OS architecture at all. Size of data types are determined by the compiler and only by the compiler. When it comes to built-in data types, the program is always 100% isolated from the OS/architecture by the compiler. I assume that the OP is compiling the same project by the same compiler every time. There can't be any difference in data type sizes in that case.

Comment: @AndreyT: "do not depend on the OS architecture at all" is a bit strong, but I get the feeling I'm misunderstanding your point. MS dictates the sizes of several data types in Windows on x86 and x86_64 (differently!) and the same types have different sizes on a linux OS with the same architecture. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @rubenvb: The compiler's data types have absolutely nothing to do with what OS "dictates". OS does not even have a concept of data type, or more precisely the OS-level concept of data type is not in any way related to the language-level concept. In fact, OS can't dictate anything. The only situation when language and OS meet is when there's access to OS-specific API. But OS specific API is not normally formulated in therms of language data types. For example, Windows API is uses aliased types like `INT`, `LONG` and so on, not `int` or `long`.

Comment: This is done specifically because Windows `INT` is not generally related to C/C++ int in any way. My "do not depend on the OS architecture at all" statement is absolutely precise. I don't see anything in the language specification that would imply any dependency on the OS. There's a weak non-binding optional relation to underlying hardware, but not to OS.

Comment: You're answer is a great programming tip. Hard coded sizes should not be used where the compiler can get you the correct size. In this particular case, the sizes don't change between 32bit and 64bit according to MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: @AndreyT I understand your point, but I think you're still slightly off. The compiler does make the decision, but it's based mainly on the target it's compiling for, not on the compiler. "I assume that the OP is compiling the same project by the same compiler every time. There can't be any difference in data type sizes in that case." It has nothing to do with whether or not you're compiling with the same __compiler__. It's whether you're compiling for the same __target__. How the compiler chooses the size of the data types for this target is, however, left for the compiler to decide.

Comment: To clarify: by target, I mean target processor architecture, not target OS

Answer (score 1):

Windows-7 has a feature called fault-tolerant-heap which ,as it says, is tolerant about some faulty buffer accesses. Windows XP doesn't have this feature (Vista ,I don't know). There is a video about it on channel9.msdn.com or sysinternal.com (forgot exactly where) by Mark Russinovich.